# Using Python to generate implicitly OAuth2 Access Token like Postman

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, postman

In Postman you can generate new access token (oAuth 2.0) with Grant Type Implicit. For that you declare a Callback Url, Auth URL, Client ID and Scope.

[Example in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOpgG.png)

How to write a Python Script that does the same. Does something like this already exist?

Comment: You can use this library by MS  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. 
I have found that although it doesn't meet the requirements I got and explained here, it is best in my case to avoid the implicit flow altogether :)